# timestamped data file parser in java

Tags: java, parsing

I have a weird data file which need to be parsed. 
This is more of a logic question than a code question.
It looks somewhat like this

```
01-11-2012 18:00:24 
01-11-2012 18:00:39 
01-11-2012 18:00:54
dataline1 
01-11-2012 18:01:09 
dataline2 
dataline3 
01-11-2012 18:01:24 
dataline4 
03-07-2010 18:01:39
```

The expected out put should be

```
01-11-2012 18:00:24,empty 
01-11-2012 18:00:39,empty
.
.
01-11-2012 18:01:09,dataline2;dataline3
```

Any ideas how to do this? I tried reading through buffered reader and having multiple ifs but couldn't get the logic straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying to parse each line using a SimpleDateFormat with the appropriate pattern (looks like "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), then catching java.text.ParseException and considering those as data lines instead? You would simply need to keep track of the last date you parsed, then associate all subsequent data lines with that date until the next time you run across a date.

Comment: I am not sure using exceptions is a good idea. is it a recommended practice or just a way to do it? i was thinking about using LineNumber reader. identifying linenumbers with timestamps and then reading data within those line numbers.

Comment: Typically it's not a great idea. But in this case, you don't really know if it's a date or not unless you try to parse it, or without basically duplicating the work that SimpleDateFormat is already doing. So in this case I would say the (normally undesirable) design is worth the tradeoff.

Comment: okay. thats what i thought. Thanks. lemme try this. Thanks.

Comment: hi, Thanks for the reply. I still did not like the approach of handling it in exception so i used another approach by adding non timestamp lines to a list and resetting the list everytime a new timestamp was discovered. It might not be the best approach but It worked better for me.